# Zend Framework 2: How can I use my Abtract model for extending a model?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a project with structure: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6hBvUW6YcomNHZJYUxvbTgxNkE

This is my AbstractTable.php:

```
namespace AdminManage\Model;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
class AbstractTable{
protected $tablegateway;
protected $table;
protected $serviceLocator;
protected $adapter;

public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway) {
    $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    $this->table = $this->tableGateway->getTable();
}

public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator){
    $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    return $this;
}

public function getServiceLocator(){
    return $this->serviceLocator;
}

public function setDbAdapter(Adapter $adapter){
    $this->adapter = $adapter;
    return $this;
}
public function getDbAdapter(){
    return $this->adapter;
}

public function fetchAll(){
    return $this->tablegateway->select();
}

public function getTable(){
    if(!$this->table)
        $this->table = $this->tableGateway->getTable();
    return $this->table;
}
}
```

This is my CategoryTable.php:

```
namespace Category\Model;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
use AdminManage\Model\AbstractTable;
class CategoryTable extends AbstractTable {
public function getListCategory() {
    $adapter = $this->getDbAdapter ();
    $sql = new Sql ( $adapter );
    $select = $sql->select ( array (
            "c" => "category" 
    ) )->join ( array (
            "cd" => "category_description" 
    ), "c.category_id = cd.category_id" );
    echo $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject ( $select )->getSql ();
}
}
```

When I call getListCategory() in the controller, has an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'AdminManage\Model\AbstractTable' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\dokusyu\htdocs\admin\dokusyu_be\module\Course\src\Category\Model\CategoryTable.php on line 5.
```

How can I fix this error? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ZF2 refer all files from root folder of your host, try creating a subdomain and and copy the files and access the pages